# Downgrade glibc on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, glibc

Ubuntu 18.04 comes with glibc 2.27. This breaks some tools I'm currently using for a project. Is there any way for me to downgrade glibc in 18.04 to 2.26? apt-cache shows that only version 2.27 is available in the repo.

Comment: You use `dpkg` to downgrade. Please see the man page for it. But also ... please don't. A safer and more stable option is to create a chroot or container for your project running the lower version.

Comment: I can't use dpkg because 2.26 isn't in the repos, and I can't run in a chroot because I need X. Right now I'm using a VM, but the performance overhead is too much.

Comment: "I can't use dpkg because 2.26 isn't in the repos," That is a weird comment: with `dpkg` you manually download the packages you need from the Ubuntu version you want to use and install them lowest dependency first. You do not use a repo for that.

Comment: Ah, I misread it as apt. Manually installing just the package might break dependencies, and recovering from a broken glibc would be a nightmare.

Comment: Stick with 16.04?

Comment: It's kinda hard to stick with 16.04 after having upgraded. In the end it was easier to just update the tool with glibc 2.27 support than doing a new install of 16.04.